# Android XML Parse Exception all of a sudden

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, sax

My code was working fine yesterday, but I start it up again today and am getting the error

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

The xml in question doesn't have any funky characters. It is stored in a String variable called "xml". To be fair, I wasn't really sure how to deal with that and was just going off of some tutorials, but here was my attempt.

```
out = new PrintWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII"));
InputStream is = mySocket.getInputStream();

...
String xml = the stuff that was read in with br.read();
...

SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();

DataHandler myDataHandler = new DataHandler();
xmlR.setContentHandler(myDataHandler);
xmlR.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
myData = myDataHandler.getData();
```

Where did I go wrong?

Update: The xml starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

so it doesn't seem that "line 1, column 0" actually has anything wrong with it.

Update 2: I found that is.available() is returning 0.... How do I make do with the fixing?

Comment: Show us the contents of `xml`. (Well, the start of it, at least.)

Comment: I strongly suspect you are not getting any response (or) part of response. I would suggest log the response.

Comment: @GrahamBorland Updated. Do you need to see more of the xml?

Comment: @thinksteep I just added a System.out.println((char)br.read()); in there and I'm getting some of the xml to print. But not all of it.

Comment: You might try a complete rebuild. Sometimes Android gets into a funky state with stuff like this... It's rarer now than it used to be, but...

Comment: I think that a complete rebuild is a little premature here. There are a number of other things that could be causing the problem, and if you rebuild, the same way, you are going to have the same problem. Generally a rebuild is the last thing you'll ever need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was in the end, but I changed several things and have it somewhat working. Here's what I changed:

I changed

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII"));
InputStream is = mySocket.getInputStream();
```

to

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
```

And I didn't include this in the original question (it was part of the "..."), but I got rid of the condition

```
if(in.available()>0)
```

because it was returning 0 even though read() worked just find without it. This is probably just a temporary hack though, and I'll need to figure out why it's returning 0 and find a legitimate fix...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are specifying you encoding method. Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

You always need to define how you are encoding your data, otherwise, you will have problems. You also might want to change this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII"));
```

to this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
```

Here is a great article that talks about the importance of specifying how you are encoding your data:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already had that first line. I made the change in the br line too, and it didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you have the `encoding="utf-8"`? It seems like you  just had: `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>` You have to have the `encoding="utf-8"` in all your xml files. Otherwise, you will have problems. Can you also post the entire XML file?